# Compass and My location button position on map in flutter

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, flutter, compass

I want to do repositioning of Compass and Location Button on GoogleMap and tried to give position to them by adding padding on map but not works.It always shows on the top of Map and haven't found the way to position them. [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37588)

My Google Map code:

```
          Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              compassEnabled:true,
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(mylat, mylan),
                zoom: 7.0,
              ),
              markers: _markers.values.toSet(),
              polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(polylines.values),
            ),
            searchContainer(),
          ],
        ),
```

[image: Goole Map Screeshot]

Answer (score 1):

for the latest version of google_maps_flutter, you can always disable the compass and my location buttons and make your own one by positioning them with Stack

```
GoogleMap googleMap = GoogleMap(
      onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
      compassEnabled: _compassEnabled,
      myLocationButtonEnabled: _myLocationButtonEnabled,
    );
```

use [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) or [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) for customized compass heading and current location information

Answer (score 1):

Tried today inside a Stack like in the question with the padding argument using `EdgeInsets.only()` and it works well in Android.

Here's a example:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(50.45, 4.25),
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Compass button**

   At this time, there is no way to change the compas position in the
   Map.
2. **My Location Button**

   I had the same issue with location button, what I did is to disable
   the default button and create my own button with my own style then I
   placed where I want to using the `Stack` widget. I didn't the same with Compass button since I didn't need to, it logic can be dificult to replicate too.